# Limit the height of ListView to 3 ListItems, then allow scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to limit the height of ListView in such a way that when the ListView has more than 3 ListItems, the ListView height doesn't increase but allows scrolling.

It means that the ListView starts scrolling if contains more than 3 items in the list.
The maximum height of listview is the height with 3 rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height that each of your ListView items will be (in this example, let's say 48dp), you can easily define your ListView as

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="144dp" />
```

The default behaviour of the list view is to add items, and only enable scrolling once they go outside its bounds.

Hard coding the height of the ListView isn't really ideal though. ListViews make ideal candidates for taking up remaining screen space within a layout, as generally they're used to display a large amount of information.